# How to remove unwanted keys from rest-assured response object and assert remaining object data with constant variable having json string using java

Tags: java-8, rest-assured, web-api-testing

In rest-assured test cases I am getting response as mentioned, where I want to remove keys such as "updated_at", "deleted_at", "created_at" and "notice" and then assert this response object with expected json string constant which contains 'settings'

```
{ 
    "notice": "The Settings are updated successfully.",
    "settings": {
    "push_notification": {
        "enabled": true,
        "credentials": [{
            "key": "value"
        }],
        "service_name": "API Testing"
    },
    "created_at": "2019-05-04T14:52:32.773Z",
    "deleted_at": "false",
    "updated_at": "2019-05-07T11:23:22.781Z"
    }
}
```

For given response the expected json string is...

```
public static String SETTING_EXPECTED = "{\"push_notification\": {\"enabled\": true, \"credentials\": [{\"key\": \"value\"}], \"service_name\": \"API Testing\"}}"
```

Please help me with creating a common method using java which can be reuse for response assertions in all the test cases.

Answer (score 0):

To delete keys from response you can use below code I am using jayway jsonpath library, you need to pass Json Response and field name jsonPath, in case your it will be  "$.settings.created_at" :

```
public String deleteFieldNameFromResponse(String jsonResponse, String fieldToDelete)
            throws ParseException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        Object obj = null;
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JsonPath jsonPath = null;
        DocumentContext docCtx = null;

        obj = parser.parse(jsonResponse);

        docCtx = JsonPath.parse(obj);

        docCtx.delete(fieldToDelete);

        jsonPath = JsonPath.compile("$");

        return docCtx.read(jsonPath).toString();
    }
```